# Editing TIFF Tag

Tags: c++, tiff, libtiff

For editing tags in a tiff file, I wrote the below code but the source file did not change.

```
TIFF *tif= TIFFOpen("new.tif", "r+");
QString temp = "new artist";
TIFFSetField (tif, TIFFTAG_ARTIST, temp.c_str());
void* val;
TIFFGetField (tif, TIFFTAG_ARTIST, &val);
cerr << (char*)val;
TIFFFlushData(tif);
TIFFClose(tif);
```

The output of this code is

```
new artist
```

But when I reopen the file and get the artist tag value, it did not change

```
TIFF *tif= TIFFOpen("new.tif", "r+");
void* val;
TIFFGetField (tif, TIFFTAG_ARTIST, &val);
cerr << (char*)val;
```

output is:

```
 127.90.112117
```

Comment: What's the return value of `TIFFFlushData()`? Did the file date change?

Comment: @sb9 , no file date is not changed.

Comment: What do the `TIFF...`functions return, especially `TIFFFlushData()`?